# keep getting the same error again and again while adding facebook sdk to my asndroid studio project

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

"error :-

could not resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0
   Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            FbLoginSample:app:unspecified
>
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 
>   'https:/jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.0.0.pom'.
>
> Could not GET 
>   'https:/jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.0.0.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https:/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https:/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.0.0.pom'.
>   repo1.maven.org
>    "
>      please help i am stuck at this.
>      any help is highly appreciated.

```
my "app: build.gradle file" 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 21
 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "loginsample.murari.krishna.xyz.fbloginsample"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

}
 repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
  }
   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

Comment: What if you update the Facebook Android SDK version in this build file? Does that work?

Comment: problem solved , somehow android studio was not able to download the facebook sdk since my connection is  on proxy.   proxfier solved the problem. by the way thanks for your suggestions guys. :)